# Access a ViewModel from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing an WPF using MVVM pattern, C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have a Window that contains an UserControl (`Control1`) and that UserControl contains another UserControl (`Control2`). I have chosen this way to do it instead of using a Dialog Window (`Control2` acts as Dialog Window).

Both user controls have a Viewmodel (`Control1VM` and `Control2VM`).

I use `Control2` as a form to let users input some data that I need to start the application.

This is the MainWindow with `Control1`:

[image]

And this is `Control2` over `Control1`.

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to hide `Control2` when I click on OK or Cancel button.

This is how `Control2` is set on `Control1`:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridControl2" Margin="30" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Visibility="{Binding GridControl2Visibility}">
    <local:Control2 x:Name="userControlControl2" />
</Grid>
```

To show `Control2` and set `GridControl2Visibility` to `Visible` in `Control1VM`:

```
public Visibility GridControl2Visibility
{
    get { return gridControl2Visibility; }
    set
    {
        if (gridControl2Visibility != value)
        {
            gridControl2Visibility = value;

            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("GridControl2Visibility");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I hide `Control2` when I click on Ok or Cancel button in `Control2`? My problem is that `GridControl2Visibility` is on `Control1VM` and I can't access that class from `Control2VM`.

Comment: The common way to do that would be with the messaging capabilities of your MVVM toolkit.

Comment: Create a VM for window also and keep instance of Child VM in that. The child VM will in turn consists of its child VM instance. This way, you can control entire code from Window VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a service that both view models can access and that stores the info whether `Control2` should be visible or not. Ideally, the service would be registered as singleton with your di-container and injected into the view models.

Alternatively, you can use an event aggregator, which is basically a singleton service, too, but focused on distributing events rather than holding a state.

Comment: To do it I have followed this article: https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/simplifying-prisms-eventaggregator/

Answer (score 0):

You can use events, You can raise event from Control2VM and hadnle it in Control1VM and set GridControl2Visibility to false.